# Php, Sql query won't let me pass in a variable, i keep getting an empty Array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

So i am trying to run a Select query to my database but the query won't work when i pass in a pre defined variable. but it work only when i explicitly type it in For Example 'username', but won't let me pass in variable for example '$username'

So i have a a function in my angular file that is posting information to my php file.

Here is my php file:

```
<?php

require "loginConnect.php";

if($conn) 
{

    $gotIt = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $gotIt->{"username"});
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $gotIt->{"password"});    


    $myquery = "SELECT Email, Firstname, Lastname, Username, Password, ConfirmPassword FROM Myusers WHERE Username = '$username'";

    // creating var to store the server's results 
    // passing in $conn for connection and $myQuery
    $request = mysqli_query($conn, $myquery); 

    if ($request)
    {
        echo "the request was made successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "the request failed";
    }

    // declaring an array to store the results objects in 
    $data = array();

    // using the foreach loop to loop thu object in results 
    foreach ($request as $i) {
        $data[] = $i;
    }    
    // closing the connection and display the data 
    mysqli_close($conn);

    echo json_encode($data);

}
else //otherwise connection failed come here
{
    echo "sorry bad connection";
}


?>
```

so when i pass in the $username variable in my query i get nothing even thought i should be getting something, but when i type the username like 'theblackmamba' get what i want. even though the variable containers the same string, the variable is just not working. Please help i am super STUCK!

Comment: you forgot the fetching part

Comment: Also, do make sure `$gotIt` actually holds contents by echoing it on the page.

Comment: Oh and it better practice to be using [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Use prepared statements. If you're using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, you're doing it wrong, and there are still ways you can get hacked.